# dell idrac6 allow access to one IP address

Tags: firewall, dell, drac, dell-poweredge

I have a dell R410 with dell idrac6 (Integrated Dell Remote Access Controller 6 - Enterprise) which is in a data center in another country.   I configured my idrac with public ip address but I have to allow one IP address to have access. Please note that I could not install other physical firewall or VPN solution

Has idrac its own iptables like solution?

Answer (score 1):

It has it's own IP-based access control. It can be configured as outlined in [this](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/software/smdrac3/idrac/idrac10mono/en/ug/html/racugc2d.htm#wp1181529) section of the manual.

It's not iptables, but it does what you're looking for.